# Where is the Gunicorn config file?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

The gunicorn documentation talks about editing the config files, but I have no idea where it is.

Probably a simple answer :) I'm on Amazon Linux AMI.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation of gunicorn.
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html

You can specify the config file with .ini or a python script.

For example, from the django-skel project

```
"""gunicorn WSGI server configuration."""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ


def max_workers():    
    return cpu_count()


bind = '0.0.0.0:' + environ.get('PORT', '8000')
max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
```

And you can run the server using

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn.py.ini project.wsgi
```

Note that project.wsgi correspond to the location of your wsgi.

Comment: Yeah, but where is the default one ?

Comment: You need to create your own. I'd suggest the `/etc` directory if using Ubuntu.

Comment: how can you import variables/functions for your application into the gunicorn config file? I keep getting an `ImportError: No module named X` or `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

Comment: What about uwsgi file? Where do I find that ? or if I create it where and what will be the content?

Comment: @Sekai for default values have a look [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/config.py). for example default value of 'backlog' is [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/config.py#L561)

Comment: How can i do same thing with daphne?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905549/running-daphne-with-a-configuration-file-similar-to-gunicorn-in-django-how-to

Answer (score 27):

An example file is here: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py

You can just comment out what you don't need and then point Gunicorn at it like so:

```
gunicorn -c config.py myproject:app
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905549/running-daphne-with-a-configuration-file-similar-to-gunicorn-in-django-how-to

Answer this similar question please

Answer (score 11):

As far as default names go, Gunicorn will look for a configuration file named [`gunicorn.conf.py` in the directory where Gunicorn is executed](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/4ef01b1c100e7590ace3e1cac5a83b81974a6161/gunicorn/config.py#L527)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905549/running-daphne-with-a-configuration-file-similar-to-gunicorn-in-django-how-to

Answer this similar question please

Answer (score 10):

**Default configs are read from `site-packages/gunicorn/config.py`**

```
$ python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print('{}/gunicorn/config.py'.format(get_python_lib()))"
(output)
/somepath/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py
```

You can run `strace` to see what files, in what order are being opened by `gunicorn`

**gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000**

```
$ strace gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000
stat("/somepath/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config", 0x7ffd665ffa30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/somepath/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/somepath/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/configmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No
such file or directory)
open("/somepath/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=53420, ...}) = 0
open("/somepath/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 6
```

**gunicorn -c g_config.py app:app**

```
$ strace gunicorn -c g_config.py app:app
//    in addition to reading default configs, reads '-c' specified config file
stat("g_config.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6784, ...}) = 0
open("g_config.py", O_RDONLY)
```

Instead of modifying the config file in site-packages, create a local `gconfig.py` (any name) and define only the variables you want to set non-default value since default config file is always read.

Pass as `gunicorn -c gconfig.py`

```
$ cat gconfig.py // (eg)
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
workers = 1
timeout = 60
. . .
```

or use command line options instead of a config file:

```
gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 1 -t 60
```

***gunicorn config file attributes/flags:
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#settings***

Answer (score 1):

I did this after reading the docs:

---

1. when deploying my app through gunicorn, usually there is a file called Procfile
2. open this file, add --timeout 600

finally, my Procfile would be like:

*web: gunicorn app:app --timeout 600*