# Running Daphne with a Configuration File Similar to Gunicorn in Django - How to Specify Configuration Options

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn, datadog, daphne

I am working on a Django project and have successfully used Gunicorn with a configuration file (lu_development/gunicorn.conf.py).

I am able run my server using this command.

```
gunicorn -c lu_development/gunicorn.conf.py lu_development.wsgi:application
```

Now, I need to switch to Daphne for ASGI support, but I'm unsure about how to specify configuration options for Daphne, similar to what I did with Gunicorn.

1. How can I run Daphne with a configuration file?
2. What is the equivalent Daphne command to gunicorn -c
   lu_development/gunicorn.conf.py lu_development.wsgi:application?
3. Are there any specific parameters or considerations when using a
   Daphne configuration file?

I would appreciate any guidance or examples on running Daphne with a configuration file, and any insights on differences or similarities between Gunicorn and Daphne configuration setups. Thanks!